# zero-ing only positive values for a specific date in a multiindex pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the code showing what I want to do:

```py
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import randint

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [['a', 'b'], pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=3)], names=['area', 'date']
)
df = pd.DataFrame({n:randint(-5, 5, 6) for n in ('foo', 'bar')}, index=index)

def zero_positives_on_date(df, dt):
    for area in df.index.levels[0]:
        for col in df.columns:
            if df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[area, dt], col] > 0:
                df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[area, dt], col] = 0
    return df

print(df)
print(zero_positives_on_date(df, pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')))
```

How can I implement `zero_positives_on_date` using masks/broadcasts/indexing/etc rather than evil nested `for` loops?

The output of the above looks like this:

```
                 foo  bar
area date                
a    2021-01-01    0   -5
     2021-01-02    1    0
     2021-01-03   -1   -1
b    2021-01-01    2    3
     2021-01-02    4    1
     2021-01-03   -3    3
                 foo  bar
area date                
a    2021-01-01    0   -5
     2021-01-02    0    0
     2021-01-03   -1   -1
b    2021-01-01    2    3
     2021-01-02    0    0
     2021-01-03   -3    3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try accessing rows by `df.index.get_level_values('date')`

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')
idx = df.index.get_level_values('date')
```

---

```
x = df[idx == dt]
x[x>0] = 0
df[idx == dt] = x
```

Using `clip`:

```
df.loc[idx == dt] = df.loc[idx == dt].clip(upper=0)
```

---

```
                    foo bar
area    date        
a       2021-01-01  4   -1
        2021-01-02  0   -2
        2021-01-03  2   -3
b       2021-01-01  1   -5
        2021-01-02  0   -4
        2021-01-03  -4  -2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, using `where` and `get_index_level`:

```
dt = pd.to_datetime('2021-01-02')
df[df.index.get_level_values('date') == dt] = df[df.index.get_level_values('date') == dt].where(df<0,0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_locs` to get the positional based index for your date and overwrite that with `.clip` to zero-out the positive values.

```
def zero_positives_on_date(df, date):
    df = df.copy()

    date_row_idx = df.index.get_locs((slice(None), date))
    df.iloc[date_row_idx] = df.iloc[date_row_idx].clip(upper=0)

    return df

print(df)
                 foo  bar
area date
a    2021-01-01    0   -5
     2021-01-02    1    0
     2021-01-03   -1   -1
b    2021-01-01    2    3
     2021-01-02    4    1
     2021-01-03   -3    3

new_df = zero_positives_on_date(df, "2021-01-02")
print(new_df)
                 foo  bar
area date
a    2021-01-01    0   -5
     2021-01-02    0    0
     2021-01-03   -1   -1
b    2021-01-01    2    3
     2021-01-02    0    0
     2021-01-03   -3    3
```